# How to set Web API DependencyResolver when using MVVMLight

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, mvvm-light

I am using OWIN to self host a web api web service in a wpf desktop app that uses the galasoft mvvmlight framework.  When I attempt to dependency inject one of my model data services into the web api controller I get an error about "Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor".

I understand that a web api controller will not support dependency injection out of the box.  I've seen numerous examples detailing how to provide a custom `IDependencyResolver` when using Unity, or writing your own. Is there a straightfoward way to set the `DependencyResolver` property of the web api startup class `HttpConfiguration` object using the mvvmlight `SimpleIoc.Default`?

As a workaround I am currently setting my dataservice by calling `SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance()` in my api controller constructor.  This works, and may be functionally the same as relying on an injection mechanism, but dependency injection seems more elegant.

```
public class webApiStartup {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        // Configure Web API for self-host. 
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "FileServerApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{filename}"
            ,defaults: new { Controller = "filesController" }
        );
//*
//* The Following line of Code does not work. But intellisense suggests
//* that there is a conversion available ?
//*
        config.DependencyResolver = (IDependencyResolver)SimpleIoc.Default;

        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}

//*
//* This constructor for the web api controller works
//* but it is not as elegant as dependency injection
//*
public class filesController : ApiController
{
    ILocalDataService _LocalDataSvc = null;

    public filesController() {
        _LocalDataSvc = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ILocalDataService>();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cast

```
 config.DependencyResolver = (IDependencyResolver)SimpleIoc.Default;
```

will fail because `SimpleIoc` is not derived from `IDependencyResolver`.

Create a wrapper for the container that is derived from `IDependencyResolver`

```
public class SimpleIocResolver : IDependencyResolver {
    protected ISimpleIoc container;

    public SimpleIocResolver(ISimpleIoc container) {
        if (container == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
        }
        this.container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType) {
        try {
            return container.GetInstance(serviceType);
        } catch(Exception) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType) {
        try {
            return container.GetAllInstances(serviceType);
        } catch (Exception) {
            return new List<object>();
        }
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope() {
        return new SimpleIocResolver(container);
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        //No Op
    }
}
```

and use that when configuring

```
config.DependencyResolver = new SimpleIocResolver(SimpleIoc.Default);
```

The ApiController can then be refactored

```
public class FilesController : ApiController {
    ILocalDataService _LocalDataSvc = null;

    public FilesController(ILocalDataService svc) {
        _LocalDataSvc = svc;
    }

    //...
```

provided that the dependencies have been registered with the container.

Reference [Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection)

Comment: It's better to replace the default `IHttpControllerActivator`, instead of overriding the `DependencyResolver`. Problem with the dependency resolver is that its `GetService` method forces you to return null on a missing configuration (or incorrect configuration). This hides errors. This is a common source of errors, confusion and frustration. Just see all the SO questions titled "controller does not have a default constructor". With `IHttpControllerActivator` you don't have this problem as it is required to return a controller or throw an exception when its `Create` method is called.